# write specific item of a list to csv field

Tags: python, csv

I have a list `item['location']` as

```
[u'', u'ABC\r\n                    : DEFG']
```

I want only the 2nd element i.e `ABC\r\n         : DEFG` of the list to write it into a single CSV field. The  code i've tried is:

```
myCSV.writerow([item['location'][1].encode('utf-8')])
```

But it only returns me `ABC` in the csv field. What am I missing?

Comment: You have embedded carriage return `\r` and new line `\n`, if you want to write the entire string you have to strip them from the string

Comment: How is your quoting set up? How are you *reading* the resulting CSV file?

Comment: Are you wanting to preserve the carriage return and new line character?

Comment: @EdChum: Not necessarily; the `csv` module can quote such columns just fine, if the OP didn't tamper with the quoting configuration *and* whatever reads the CSV honours quoting as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `\r\n` after ABC will start a new row. Therefore, the field will only contain `ABC`.

As EdChum said, remove the `\r\n` from the string. 
If the `\r\n` is necessary information try to encode the string before putting it into your CSV file.

Comment: Not necessarily; the `csv` module certainly can quote the field correctly but it depends on what is *reading* the resulting file if the quoting is honored (as well as the `csv.writer()` configuration that influences quoting).